# Path to import CSS file from Magento template

Tags: magento-1.9

In **\app\design\frontend\base\default\template\index.php** I need to import a JS file from the Magento root.

How do I give the path in the script tag's src attribute?

I have tried the following. I need the same for the CSS.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>js/myfolder/script.js"></script>  <!--working-->

<!-- I get style.css not found
CSS path: html/magento/skin/frontend/rwd/default/css/folder/style.css-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('css/folder/style.css',array('_secure'=>true));?>" media="all" />
```

I get a forbidden error when using the above.

Comment: you can use getBaseUrl()

Comment: How come you're doing it in index.php? The usual method is via XML unless I'm missing something.

Comment: try to remove array('secure'=>'true'), but in which templates you are trying to add ?

Comment: index.php inside template folder?